# Having Trouble with SD DMA on STM32L452 MCU

Tags: embedded, stm32, sd-card

I am having trouble making SDMMC work with DMA in 4 bit mode. I tried with FreeRTOS and without FreeRTOS didnt get anyresult. But it works perfectly without DMA.

It gives either Rx Overrun error or timeout error.

I tried it with different SD card, Different clock speeds, Different configuration no change.

I would really be grateful if someone can help me with this or have working example.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ST HAL drivers? Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: @A.R.C.thak you for replying. I'm using Hal drivers with the standard fmount, fopen and fwrite function. It works well in with another MCUs. I think this is a well known problem for this MCU as you can see in this link (https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BKAwor/stm32l452-dma-sdio-overrun-issue). However I can't understand what is the solution.